# Будет ли работать скрипт без .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, vbscript

Будет ли работать скрипт если на машине нет .NET Framework?

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_NTLogEvent instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Message: " & objItem.Message
Next
```

Comment: А как Вы его запускаете этот скрипт?

Comment: Скрипт использует встроенный в Windows инструментарий WMI. Можно даже сказать, что реализация же .Net Framework находится выше по уровню. Непонятно как соотносится приведенный код VB-скрипта и Framework?

Answer (score 3):

Да, будет.

Системный компонент [WSH (Windows Script Host)](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_overview.mspx?mfr=true) выпущен значительно раньше .NET 1.0 и имеет собственный итерпретатор языков [VBScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_Scripting_Edition), [JScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript).

Несмотря на то, что многие синтаксические конструкции VBScript совпадают с аналогичными конструкциями Visual Basic - это разные языки. JScript также часто путают с Java Script по той же причине.

В настоящее время, PowerShell потихоньку вытесняет WSH, так как предоставляет гораздо больше возможностей, в том числе языковых (C# например), так что имеет смысл подумать о замене скриптов для WSH скриптами для PowerShell.

Инструментарий WMI также не имеет отношения к .NET и является частью ОС.